# Separation of Variables to Find the General Solution to a DE

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, quadratics

> Use the separation of variables to find the general solution to $y' = 3y - y^2$.

Given $$\frac{dy}{dt} = 3y - y^2,$$
I can rearrange this to 
$$\frac{1}{3y-y^2}dy = dt$$

and using partial fraction decomposition

where $$\frac{1}{3y-y^2} = \frac{A}{y} + \frac{B}{3-y},$$

I get that $$A = B = \frac{1}{3}$$.

Then I have $$(\frac{1}{3y} - \frac{1}{3(3-y)})dy = dt$$

Integrating both sides, $$\frac{1}{3} \ln(|y|) + \frac{1}{3} \ln(|3-y|) = t+c_1,$$

which can also be written as $$\ln(|y(3-y)|) = 3t + c_2$$
$$\rightarrow |y(3-y)| = Ce^{3t}$$

I guessed I could solve for $y$ in this quadratic equation, but that doesn't give me the right solutions (which I have access to). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what is the answer ?  check it should be $\ln |y-3|$

Comment: $y(t) = 0$ or $y(t) = \frac{3}{1+ce^{-3t}}$

Comment: when you evaluated A and B you changed the sign

Comment: oh! but I'm still not quite clear on which sign(s) you're talking about...

Comment: $$(13y−13(3−y))dy=dt$$ The line before it was a positive sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made some sign mistakes. Here I suppose $y \ne 0, y \ne 3$
$$\frac {dy}{y(3-y)}=dx$$
$$\frac {dy}{y}+\frac {dy}{3-y}=3dx$$
$$\frac {dy}{y}-\frac {dy}{(y-3)}=3dx$$
$$\ln| \frac {y}{(y-3)}|=3x+K$$
$$| \frac {y}{(y-3)}|=Ce^{3x}$$
$$ y(1-Ce^{3x})=-3Ce^{3x}$$
Rearrange terms you should get the right answer
$$ y=\frac {-3Ce^{3x}}{(1-Ce^{3x})}$$
$$ y=\frac {3Ke^{3x}}{(1+Ke^{3x})}=\frac {3}{(1+Ce^{-3x})}$$

Comment: I'm confused, though, because I am supposed to have $e^{-3x}$ but from what you gave me as a hint (and what I solved), I keep on getting just $e^{3x}$.

Comment: what is exactly the answer you find ? @singularity

Comment: well, from where you left off, for example, I get $y = (3-y)Ce^{3t}$. Grouping like variables together, I get $y(1+Ce^{3t}) = 3$, which gives me $y = \frac{3}{1+Ce^{3t})$, which is slightly different from the original one since it's supposed to be $y = \frac{3}{1+Ce^{-3t})$

Comment: @singularity I added some lines if you have any questions don't hesitate.